# Unable to compile curl-rust on Windows 32bits, undefined references to pthread functions

Tags: windows, curl, gcc, rust

I come across this error when trying to compile [curl-rust](https://github.com/alexcrichton/curl-rust) on Windows 32bits with MSYS2 installed. It seems that 'pthread' is not supported by MSYS2 / mingw32.

```
 error: linking with gcc failed: exit code: 1

 D:/Applications/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o):(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to pthread_mutex_init'

 D:/Applications/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o):(.text+0xfd9): undefined reference topthread_once'

 D:/Applications/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o):(.text+0xfe5): undefined reference to pthread_mutex_lock'

 D:/Applications/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o):(.text+0x10f4): undefined reference topthread_once'

 D:/Applications/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o):(.text+0x1100): undefined reference to pthread_mutex_lock'

 D:/Applications/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o):(.text+0x11cb): undefined reference topthread_once'

 D:/Applications/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o):(.text+0x11d7): undefined reference to pthread_mutex_lock'

 D:/Applications/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o):(.text+0x1239): undefined reference topthread_mutex_unlock'

 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could there be something I missed in my MSYS2 install?

I cannot find much about this error online except that this function is not on Windows.

**Example :**

*main.rs*

```
// https://crates.io/crates/curl 
// http://alexcrichton.com/curl-rust/curl/index.html
extern crate curl;
use curl::easy::Easy;

fn main() {
    let mut easy = Easy::new();
}
```

*Cargo.toml*

```
[package]
name = "linksbypage"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["LeMoussel"]

[dependencies]
curl = "*"
```

Windows (GNU ABI ) Rust version: 1.11.0, Cargo version: 0.12.0-nightly.

Comment: Looks like a missing library name at the command line. What's the command line?

Comment: @ harper, the command line is simply : `cargo build`

Comment: Norepro, I use the same setup and it works

Comment: @набиячлэвэли on Windows 32bits?

Comment: yes, Windows 10 to be exact